# How to make encrypted fields unique in django?

Tags: django, encryption, model, unique-key

I use fernet_fields extension to make one of my fields encrypted, however I need data in this field to be unique. Since data in encrypted field is always different, it doesn't support uniqueness. But I need db to store only unique records. So how do I do this? I have idea to make additional irreversible md5 charfield, but is there a convenient way to make both fields being recorded simulteniously by setting some one parameter of my model?

Comment: Why do you say that encrypted fields are not unique? They should be more unique than a MD5 hash. The scary thing about fernet_fields after looking a [django-fernet-fields!](https://django-fernet-fields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is that there is no information about the encryption! Digging deeper [Fernet Spec](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md) helps.

Comment: That's must be lost in translation, I mean I need raw data to be unique, of course encrypted data will be unique too. I mean unique records like primary key. Right now I can store one string in my table many times, It will be uniquely encrypted, but I want there to be one certain string.

Comment: @zaph Using fernet-fields because it works with python 3.5

Comment: The encryption specification is 1st rate so it looks like a good choice. The spec is just butted a little.

Comment: I think I'll go with my idea, found this solution
https://www.stavros.io/posts/how-replace-django-model-field-property/

Comment: What about the encryption?

Comment: data to be stored is always more than 15 symbols, it won't be reasonable to brute force md5, and I can add some salt

Comment: So you are not going to encrypt the data, instead create a hash? But the question was about encrypting fields.

Comment: @zaph Since fernet-fields chooses a "unique IV" during encryption it's possible to get different ciphertexts for the same plaintext. A way to enforce uniqueness is to run a simple hash function over the plaintext and store it in a separate column with the unique constraint. That's probably what OP was trying to say. Of course, if the plaintext has low entropy, it would be best to use a slow hash function such as PBKDF2, scrypt, bcrypt, Argon2 (i.e. for passwords, but then passwords should never be encrypted).

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes, you got me right, but what do you mean by `passwords should never be encrypted`?

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: @ArtjomB. oh, I got it, I'm not going to encrypt passwords.

Comment: The word "unique" has several meanings: adjective: *being the only one of its kind; unlike anything else*, predicate (unique to) *belonging or connected to (one particular person, group, or place)*. In this case the usage is (unique to): the encrypted text it unique to the plain text. I missed this usage.